# How to group numeric attribute ranges similar to prices in layered navigation?

Tags: attributes, layered-navigation

I have a numeric attribute that is a size (in cm). I would like to group products into ranges of the attribute similar to how prices are grouped.

So if I have several products with sizes 151cm, 152 cm, 153cm it should group them into a "150cm - 155cm" option in layered navigation.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just finished setting up layered navigation for products with different suggested age ranges.  I ended up making a new attribute for the layered navigation, with a set of predetermined values.  I was also struggling to get fre-form values grouped in the layered nav.

So in your case, you would keep the actual size field and put your product sizes in there for display on the product pages, then you have another attribute called Size Range.  In Size Range, you have all of the ranges that you want to be shown in the layered nav, like 145cm-150cm, 150c-155cm, ect.  Maybe multi-selectable so that a product that's 150cm could be in both? (or just avoid any overlaps)  All of those values will show up in the layered nav, and it will work.

The downside...you're entering the size twice, once for display and once for layered nav purposes, yuck.  I load new products with a script using the api, so for me this was a bit of coding and won't require ongoing double data entry.  If you're loading a lot of products through the magento interface this might be annoying.

Answer (score 0):

"If you're loading a lot of products through the magento interface this might be annoying."

Create new attribute as @RightClick suggest and

Magento provide an attribute by below code

```
$product->setAttributeCode($newValue)
$ProductObject->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'attribute_Code');
```

**Example:**

```
$productIds = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));

foreach($products as $product)
{
    $product->setSpecialFromDate('2010-10-28');
    // below code use for time format 
    $product->setSpecialFromDateIsFormated(true);
    $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'special_from_date');
}
```

Or use any bulk product import module for update that attribute to bulk of Products.
For bulk product import module you have to create multidimensional array

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'sku' => 'simple1',
        'attribute_code' => 'range_value1',
    ),
    array(
        'sku' => 'simple2',
        'attribute_code' => 'range_value2',
    ),
    array(
        'sku' => 'grouped',
        'attribute_code' => 'range_value3',
    ),
);

// now update that array collection in one go

try {
    /** @var $import AvS_FastSimpleImport_Model_Import */
    $import = Mage::getModel('fastsimpleimport/import');
    $import
        ->setUseNestedArrays(true)
        ->processProductImport($data);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($import->getErrorMessages());
}
```

[Link for AvS_FastSimpleImport](https://avstudnitz.github.io/AvS_FastSimpleImport/options.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/75956)

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Thanks for your suggestion. As this is my first answer on stackoverflow and i get to know somthing new by you.